# Select or free text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any JavaScript / jquery library to turn an input into a select where the "other" option is a free text? Or do I have to write it by myself? Thanks

Comment: You mean turn an input into a combobox with support for custom value input? No, you have to code it yourself or use widget libraries, there's plenty of them out there, just google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). That way it will allow arbitrary text and will show a drop down that is filtered by user input (if it is relevant to your situation).

Answer (score 0):

try the following- 
javascript function as follows:

```
function changeselect() 
{ 
var mdiv=document.getElementById('other'); 
var cdiv=document.getElementById('select'); 
if(cdiv.options[cdiv.selectedIndex].value=='other') 
{ 
mdiv.style.visibility='visible'; 
} 
else 
{ 
mdiv.style.visibility='hidden'; 
} 
}
```

HTML as follows: 
.......

```
<select id="select" name="select" onChange="changeselect()"> 
<option value"please">Please select One</option> 
<option value="car">Car</option> 
<option value="bike">Bike</option> 
<option value="other">Other</option> 
</select> 
<INPUT id="other" type="text" name="other">
```

...........

Answer (score 0):

The dojo toolkit offers a full set of custom form widgets. The [ComboBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/ComboBox.html) would work in your case (see also the [FilteringSelect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html))